# gganimation: animate bars one by one and retatin previously shown

Tags: r, ggplot2, animation, plot, gganimate

I wonder how to animate `geom_bar` from `ggplot2` with `gganimate` in such a way that previously shown bar stay and next come.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
 
a <- data.frame(group=c("A","B","C"), values=c(3,2,4), frame=rep('a',3))
b <- data.frame(group=c("A","B","C"), values=c(5,3,7), frame=rep('b',3))
df1 <- rbind(a,b)  
 
Plot1 <-
  ggplot(data= df1, aes(x = group, y = values, fill = group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  theme_bw() +
  transition_states(
    states            = group
  , transition_length = 2
  , state_length      = 1
  ) 
Plot1
```

The above given code shows bar one by one but fade the previously shown. However, I want to retain already shown bars. Any thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `?shadow_mark()` from the `gganimate` package. I think this achieves what you are looking to accomplish:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

a <- data.frame(group=c("A","B","C"), values=c(3,2,4), frame=rep('a',3))
b <- data.frame(group=c("A","B","C"), values=c(5,3,7), frame=rep('b',3))
df1 <- rbind(a,b)  

Plot1 <-
  ggplot(data= df1, aes(x = group, y = values, fill = group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  theme_bw() +
  transition_states(
    states            = group
    , transition_length = 2
    , state_length      = 1
  ) +
  shadow_mark() # keeps past data displayed
Plot1
```

Comment: Thanks @BDuff for very useful answer. Much appreciated.